# Why do I get a compilation error?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am using GCC 4.8 to compile the following code:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
    std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&& ...args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
}

struct S {
    template<class... Args>
    static std::unique_ptr<S> create(Args&&... args) {
        return make_unique<S>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
private: // if I remove this line, then the compilation is OK
    S(int) {}
    S() = default;
};

int main() {
    auto s1 = S::create(); // OK
    auto s2 = S::create(0); // Compilation error
}
```

Can anyone explain me the reason of this error from the compiler?

> main.cpp: In instantiation of 'std::unique_ptr make_unique(Args&&
>   ...) [with T = S; Args = {int}]':
>
> main.cpp:11:58:   required from 'static std::unique_ptr
>   S::create(Args&& ...) [with Args = {int}]'
>
> main.cpp:20:26:   required from here
>
> main.cpp:14:5: error: 'S::S(int)' is private
>
> ```
>  S(int) {}
>  ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:5:65: error: within this context
>        return std::unique_ptr(new T{std::forward(args)...});
>
> ```
>                                                              ^
> ```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can anyone explain me the reason of this error from the compiler?

The constructor which takes `int` is declared to be `private` which is why it is giving compilation error. Note that the constructor is getting invoked from `make_unique` (which doesn't have access to private members), not from `create`.

However, you're probably wondering why the first call to to `create()` compiles fine, I think it is because **GCC has bug**. It should not compile even in this case, because the default constructor is declared to be `private` as well. **Clang correctly gives error for both calls** ([see this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d6e4e7e1ae2c0c5)).

Anyway, if you want to keep them `private`, then make `make_unique` a friend of the class.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is fairly simple:

The constructor is not called from within `S::create`, but from within the `::make_unique` function template, which does not have access to the private member function `S::S(int)`.

A simple fix would be to call `new` yourself (see [here](http://ideone.com/sqUSTR)).

Actually, the more interesting question is why it does not error on the first call as well...

Comment: I think OP’s issue is that he (quite reasonably!) wants to avoid calling `new` explicitly in code.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ struct, all members are public by default. In a class declaration, members are private by default. In your case, constructors have been made private, that's why you get the error: S::S(int) was private

So, make the changes as:

```
public: 
    S(int) {}
    S() = default;
```

Comment: I don't want to make constructors public. This is why I have introduced create(), Furthermore, for some reasons the private S() constructor does not make the compilation fail when it's private, while S(int) makes the compilation fail...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the class's constructors private, you must make any non-member user (here: `make_unique`) a friend:

```
struct S {
  template<typename T, typename ...Args>
  friend std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&& ...args);
  // rest as before
};
```

Alternatively, you may avoid `make_unique<>` and directly create the `unique_ptr<S>` from a static member:

```
struct S {
  template<class... Args>
  static std::unique_ptr<S> create(Args&&... args)
  { return std::unique_ptr<S>(new S{std::forward<Args>(args)...}); }
  // rest as before
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If some constructor is private, it means that no one but the class itself (and friends) should be able to create instances of it using that constructor.

To create instance of a class which has only privates constructors, you have to use a static method.